# MySql cant add data

Tags: python, mysql, database

When i try to add the user to the database on the website this error comes out.

**MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")**

````
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'flask_contacts'

mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/')
def Index():
    return  render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add_contact', methods = ['POST'])
def add_contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fullname    = request.form['fullname']
        phone       = request.form['phone']
        email       = request.form['email']
        # Cursor created
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        # Request
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO contacts (fullname, phone, email) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)',
        (fullname, phone, email))
        # Aplly request
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return 'recived'

@app.route('/edit')
def edit_contact():
    return 'edit contact'

@app.route('/delete')
def delete_contact():
    return 'delete contact'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port = 3000, debug = True)```
````

Comment: Sounds like you entered the wrong password, or else your user doesn't have INSERT privilege on the `flask_contacts` schema or the `contacts` table.

Comment: You should have a user with only the needed rights that you use in your website scripts. Maybe this is just testing?

Comment: Solved! it was the password !

Comment: ^^ **Never** use the `root` account for applications, especially web applications! Create a separate account and assign it limited permissions